# Spark Scala Loop according to a specific Column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a table that looks like the one given below:

```
Col_1   Col_2   Col_3   Col_4   Col_5
1   1a  data    data    data
1   1b  data    data    data
1   1c  data    data    data
1   1d  data    data    data
2   2a  data    data    data
2   2b  data    data    data
2   2c  data    data    data
```

Col_1 is associated with Col_2.
When I query this for individual record:

```
val A = spark.table(“table_name”).filter($”Col_1” ==== “1”).select(“Col_2”).distinct.show()
```

I get the output as:

```
Col_2
1a
1b
1c
1d
```

Now, I want to run this as a loop. Taking values from Col_1 and giving the output associated with Col_2.
Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? You already have the Col2 values associated with each Col1.

Comment: @Ethan I want a loop where in value 2 is taken from Col_1 and it gives all the values associated with Col_1 from Col_2. Then next take value 3 and so on.

Comment: Are you trying to run some sort of aggregation? Spark has native grouping functions on Dataframes, but they're centered around aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```scala
import spark.implicits._

val inDf: DataFrame = spark.table("table_name")
val res: Array[DataFrame] = inDf.select($"Col_1")
  .distinct()
  .collect().map(_.get(0))
  .par //optional to parallel execute
  .map { col1 =>
    inDf.filter($"Col_1" === col1)
      .select($"Col_2")
  }.toArray
```